# Building a shared library created a static library instead

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, mingw, static-linking

I am trying to build libass into a shared library with static linking under MinGW-w64. When I configure with

```
./configure --disable-static --enable-shared
```

it generates the shared library (dynamically-linked) as expected. However, when I attempt to force static linking by setting

```
LDFLAGS=-static
```

instead of generating a statically-linked shared library (.dll with no dependency), it generates a static library (.a).

I am almost certain that I have all the dependent static libraries and no error or warning message is shown in the make process.

Can anyone please shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libtool` says No.

The package's stock autotools `ltmain.sh` script parses the linkage flags and
if it finds `-static` it will not build a shared library, just a static
one.

Which is the most it could reasonably do, because you can't statically link a shared
library. A shared library must consist entirely of Position Independent (PIC)
code or the linkage will fail, whereas a static linkage will call for the linkage
of non-PIC object files, contributed by the non-PIC standard and runtime libraries,
if nothing else.

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts("foo");
}
```

Build a dynamically linked shared library:

```
$ gcc -c -fPIC foo.c
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
$ file libfoo.so
libfoo.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), \
dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=1adff7204d84d138a80bc4b6f3f38211e4b42812, \
not stripped
```

Attempt to build a statically linked shared library:

```
$ gcc -c -fPIC foo.c
$ gcc -shared -static -o libfoo.so foo.o
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/crtbeginT.o: \
relocation R_X86_64_32 against hidden symbol `__TMC_END__' cannot be used \
when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer because the root of the problem is indeed libtool consuming the `-static` option instead of passing it down. The solution I found is to pass `-Wc,-static` into `LDFLAGS` instead so libtool would pass down `-static` to gcc when in link mode to force static linking of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The static lib is just an ar package. 
You can use command of ar to make the pack and unpack it.

Comment: Thanks for answering! My question is that I'm expecting the output to be a shared library (.DLL) but I'm getting a static library  (.a) instead.